# upload a pdf to s3 from frontend -> node js -> s3

Tags: pdf, amazon-s3, encoding, base64

frontend app:

```
const readURL = (input) => {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.fileName = input.files[0].name;
      reader.onload = async function (e) {
        uploadPhoto(reader, e);
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  };

const uploadPhoto = (reader, e) =>  {
    let client = new ServerData();
    client.put("/images/upload", {
      imageBase64: reader.result,
      name: e.target.fileName,
      typeOfUpload: "xxxx-bank",
    }).then(uploadResult => {
       ....
    })
  };
```

backend `node.js`

```
fileContent = base64Image // directly from frontend
fileContent = Buffer.from(base64Image,'base64'); //tried this as well 



let params = {
            Bucket: 'bucket',
            Key: 'name.pdf',
            Body: fileContent,
            ContentEncoding: 'base64',
            ACL: 'private'
        }

let upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({
            params: params
        });
```

notice the `fileContent`
for images it works and i'm using

```
Buffer.from(base64Image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),'base64');
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution was

```
Buffer.from(base64Image.replace(/^data:.+;base64,/, ""),'base64');
```